# navigation bar item's label from array

Tags: flutter

I am creating a bottom navigation bar in flutter. I would like to pick the labels from an array. The following program throws an error "Values in a const list literals must be constants". I understand that the the list of navigation bar items in the scaffold is declared const and we cannot use the non-const string arrays. How to fix this problem?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  // final List _children = [];
  Text titleText = new Text('Pensor');
  var tabLabels =  ['Home', 'Water', 'Insights', 'Cabliration', 'Settings'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: titleText,
      ),
      // body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: tabLabels[0], // <-- Here is the error. The tabLabels are not const. 
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.water_damage),
            label: 'Water',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.insights),
            label: 'Insights',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.biotech),
            label: 'Calibration',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove const

```
items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: tabLabels[0], 
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.water_damage),
            label: 'Water',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.insights),
            label: 'Insights',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.biotech),
            label: 'Calibration',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),

        ],
```